# Diagonalizing symmetric 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If ***A*** is a $2\times2$ symmetric matrix ($A^T = A$) where $b$ does not equal zero ($a$'s are on the diagonal, $b$'s occupy the other $2$ spaces), find a matrix $X$ such that $X^T AX$ is diagonal.

What is the simple way to solve this problem (using orthogonal diagonalization intro linear algebra)?

Comment: hint: since the matrix A is symmetric and you have an orthogonal matrix X which is invertible, you can perform row operations and the associated column operation to get a diagonal matrix

Comment: The hint isn't clear enough to me. I know that the first two things are true, but I don't know what you mean by row operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just go with the computations ;)

You easily get the two eigenvalues : $\lambda_1=a-b$ and $\lambda_2=a+b$ and the corresponding eigenvectors:

$V_1=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $V_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

you can also make them have norm 1. Then:

$V_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $V_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

And thus you have your two matrices $P$ and $D$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$:

$D=\begin{pmatrix} a-b & 0 \\0 & a+b \end{pmatrix}$ and $P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

your matrix $P$ is clearly symmetric, and $P^{-1}=P^T$. And there you have it:

$A=PDP^{-1}=PDP^T$ which gives $D=P^TAP$

Comment: Thank you. I originally did this, but I scrunched it up because I thought that I had to have some general answer for X

Comment: Well you can have a general answer if you want to. Just take the general form of the eigenvectors. i.e.:

$V_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x_1^2}}\begin{pmatrix} -x_1 \\ x_1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $V_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x_2^2}}\begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It doesn't seem that it's required by the wording of the question

Comment: Well then, here you go ;)